# Know you the way export multiple sheets to One pdf without .Select and .ActiveWorkbook?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export

I found only this code. Is it possible to reference specific 2 sheets name instead of `.select` them?
Merge pages print area or something similar?

I can't enter multiple worksheets in `.ExportAsFixedFormat`

```
Sub SelectSheetsAndSaveAsPDF()

'Create and assign variables
Dim saveLocation As String
Dim sheetArray As Variant

saveLocation = "C:\Users\marks\OneDrive\Documents\myPDFFile.pdf"
sheetArray = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

'Select specific sheets from workbook, the save all as PDF
Sheets(sheetArray).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=saveLocation

End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with `Select`ing them? `sheetArray = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")` specifies 2 sheets by name. Not sure what your issue is.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to avoid ActiveSheet and Select during this operation.

Comment: I don't believe so.